# Product of strong and weakly converging sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Consider a sequence of functions $\{u_n\}\in L^2([0,T],L^2(\Omega)) $ which converges strongly to a function $u\in L^2([0,T],L^2(\Omega))$. Then $u_n \rightarrow u \;\; a.e. $ in $Q=\Omega\times[0,T]$.

Let $\gamma_n : R\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be a function $\gamma(u_n)$, which is Lipschitz continuous and bounded for each $n,\;\; e.g. \;\; 0<\gamma_* \leq \gamma_n \leq \gamma^*<\infty$. Then also $\gamma_n \rightarrow \gamma:=\gamma(u) \;\; a.e.$

Next assume that sequence $\{A_n\}\in L^2([0,T],L^2(\Omega))$ converges weakly to $A\in L^2([0,T],L^2(\Omega))$. That means that $(A_n,\phi)\rightarrow (A,\phi)$, $\forall \phi \in L^2([0,T],L^2(\Omega))$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Does the sequence $\{\gamma_n A_n\}$  converge weakly to $\gamma A$ in the space $L^2([0,T],L^2(\Omega))$?